# Dual boot Linux with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, boot, mbr

I am trying to recover an installation of Linux on my machine, preferably without having to reinstall Linux (and possibly Windows) altogether.

I have installed [Pear OS](http://pearlinux.fr/) first, and then installed Windows 7. I can no longer boot into Linux, presumably because Windows has overwritten the boot sector and/or master boot record.

I have tried to use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to gain access to my Linux install, without much luck.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What bootloader was Pear OS using before you installed Windows?

Comment: @Ramhound, I wish I could tell you! - I don't know. :S

Comment: You should research what bootloader Pear OS uses by default and come back and update your question.

Comment: It should be using GRUB bootloader (not sure which version, probably GRUB2)

Comment: Well at least tell if you have GPT partitioning with UEFI? Google if if you don't know here to look check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download a live DVD/CD/USB .iso file from one of the many Linux websites and install a new GRUB.  It should detect all existing and installed operating systems and include them in the boot choices.  There is a good tutorial on the GRUB here... http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/index.html#Top

Answer (score 1):

If you have PearOS installation CD, I think there should be option to repair boot loader on that CD. So, boot from that CD and choose boot repair. I had similar situation with Ubuntu and GRUB loader.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some problems with Ubuntu and Windows 7. I've accidentally deleted GRUB files from the `C` partition when (manually) cleaning my Windows. Since this time I was unable to boot.

So, you should do this:

1. EasyBCD-Add partition where your PearOS is to the WindowsBootloader.
2. Restart and choose your PearOS - You should receive a message why It can't boot. Google this prompt or files.